# Undefined variable located in imported SASS files

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm using Gulp to compile my SASS files. I have a main styles.scss file which I am using to import other SASS files.

My styles.scss file looks like this..

```
@import "slider/slider_style";

.slider-nav li {border-radius: $dot-rounded;}
```

My `slider/_slider_style.scss` file looks like this:

```
$dot-rounded: 30px !default;
```

When I compile I get the following error:

```
Error: Undefined variable: "$dot-rounded".
    on line 3 of styles.scss
```

I am at a complete loss as to why this is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're importing `slider_style` but your file is named `_slider_style`

Comment: Yes... but that's how SASS normally works, right? The _ is basically ignored.

Comment: According to the docs you're right. I was unaware of that.

Comment: All your variables are at the top of _slider_style.scss?  And the import port is relative to your styles.scss.